# How does vbucket solves server data loss during switching

Tags: hash, memcached, consistent-hashing

vbucket is used by memcached to dynamically add / remove servers. My question is how is it better than consistent hashing. Also when a server is added and the state changes from Pending to Active. It is done first and then vbucket points to the newly added server. So requests which were going to older ones will have to come to new ones as well and switching should happen atomically. How ?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't believe that VBuckets have actually been implemented into memcached. The only place where I know that they are used is in Couchbase which has a memcached-like caching layer in it's Couchbase Bucket.

> > My question is how is it better than consistent hashing?

VBuckets are better than consistent hashing because they are easier to move between servers then individual keys. If you rely on consistent hashing then if you want to move from two servers to three then the only way to do that is to rehash every single key in the system to the new set of servers. If you have VBuckets then you only need to move a few of the VBuckets to the new server. This in essence gives an easy way to identify which keys need to be moved and you can avoid having to visit every key in the cluster.

> > How do clients figure out where to send requests when a VBucket moves to another server?

In Couchbase each client contains a map that maps VBuckets to ip addresses. The client also has a connection to a streaming port which sends VBucket map changes. When the client gets a new map it can update where requests are routed to.

Comment: you are right that vbucket is implemented in couchbase and internally couchbase consists of memcached only which is developed by Zynga initially ( as Membase ) and I work there. I didn't get your point of moving server is easy. In consistent hashing when you add a server you don't re-hash the keys. You just add a server and it starts taking keys which fall before it now in the ring.

Comment: Right there is no re-hashing, but as a result you suffer from the cold cache problem. Instead of me explaining this here, take a look at this article http://dustin.sallings.org/2010/06/29/memcached-vbuckets.html and if you still have questions let me know.

Comment: Yes you are right again :) but see the trade-off. When a server has to be added without home-work, i.e, urgently, then you consistent hashing has the benefit and what you do is : the code can easily figure out where to go when there is a miss because a new server is added. You have max / min bound logic to figure out and then you can move the data lazily or from consumers.

Comment: Remember with VBuckets that each client should be getting immediate updates from the cluster when the VBucket map changes so the client should always be able to direct requests to the appropriate server in 1 hop too. I think one of the trade-offs in the case you mention above is that since VBuckets are moved onto the new server you cannot use the extra memory in the new server until those VBuckets have been moved. The other trade-off is that moving data lazily will temporarily increase load on your database, but with VBuckets it won't.